# C++ root any number is not displaying anything for negative numbers

Tags: c++, math

```
void y_root_x(){            


        double x_root_y;                            // Power x by y     

        cout << endl << endl;
        Get_x_and_y_power();                                    // Pulls data from Get_x_and_y_power(), gets x and y
        int even_y = y;             // decides if y is an even or odd number

        if (y == 0)                 // Test if y does not equal 0
        {
            cout << "Invalid. y cannot be 0." << endl;
        }
        else if (x < 0 && even_y % 2 == 0)      // Test if x<0 and even, if it is we cannot display data.
        {       
                cout << "Invalid answer. Negative numbers cannot be " << y << " rooted." << endl;           
        }
        else
        {
            x_root_y = pow(x,1.0/y);                    // Root x by y
            //x_root_y = nthRoot(x, y);
            cout << "  x ^ y = " << x << " ^ (1 / " << y <<
            ") = "<< x_root_y << endl;                  // Display Values
        }


}
```

For an example, if I enter -133 and 3, nan gets displayed for the answer. How do I get it to display odd roots for negative numbers?

Comment: `pow` does not support that use-case. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: If x is negative, you can only expect real solutions if 1/y is an integer. If I assume your y is a signed integer, you can "always" expect real solutions only if y is -1 or 1. For negative x and other y values, the answer is complex. I suggest you refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases
and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html

Answer (score 1):

You've got 1.0/y so rather than -133 and 3. it's -133 and 1/3 you're concerned about: the [`std::pow` documentation here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) says - in the Notes section - to use the cube-root function for that case:

> Although `std::pow` cannot be used to obtain a root of a negative number, [`std::cbrt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cbrt) is provided for the common case where exp is 1/3

Comment: the question has 1.0/3